# Switch from one UIStoryBoard Controller to another UIStoryBoard Controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swift4, swift5

Want to navigate between two `UIStoryBoard` and between different `UIViewController`. My problem is that when I tap on `UIButton` the control should transfer to the `UIViewController` from current `UIStoryBoard` to another `UIStoryBoard`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could create a ["Storyboard Reference"](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226) in the first story board and connect a segue to it

Comment: i have applied segue but asked to use some other method. programitcally

Comment: I added a link, which demonstrates the "old way" (via code) and using a segue and storyboard reference

Answer (score 0):

You can either **Push** or **Present** the new viewController 
Using Following code you can push the new view controller to your navigation controller

```
let yourVC = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ViewConrtollerID) as! YourViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: this method apply to move from one VC to another in same storyboard.Im asking for 2 storyboard movement

Comment: Look at **StoryBoardName** this is where you specify the storyboard name.

Comment: @MuhammadBilal No, you can specify the storyboard name.

Answer (score 0):

- You first need to create reference of the second storyboard in which you want to move from current. For that you need to create reference as shown in below image and set the other story board name in that. [image]

after that you can push the to that storyboard controller using below code.

```
 let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"storyboadnameToPush", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:controller storyboardId) 
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```